# SWRevealViewController not working because Value of type 'XX-ViewController' has no member 'revealViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, header-files, swrevealviewcontroller

I added SWRevealViewController.h and SWRevealViewController.m by using drag and drop. ***Bridging header pop up not came***.

I have 3 pod files also. So I just want to check whether error is coming because of 'Header file not added' or by another pod files. My code is below.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    openSlideMenuView.target = self.revealViewController()
}
```

Error is below :-

```
 Value of type 'HomeViewController' has no member 'revealViewController'
```

Comment: HomeViewController is not  a subclass of  revealViewController, add the value to viewcontroller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add SWRevealViewController.h and SWRevealViewController.m by using drag and drop.
2. Add a new file to Xcode (File > New > File), then select “Swift_bridge_header” and click “Header File“.
3. add import "SWRevealViewController.h" to Swift_bridge_header.h
4. Drag the Swift_bridge_header.h on the project navigator into Objective-C Bridging Header(Please see the following image, it is in Build Settings)

[image]

Then it will be working fine.